Divi theme and Woocommerce combo causing problems with cart and checkout page
I have taken over as an website manager for a guy who runs a webshop. His recent website manager got fired cause of selling him an faulty website who looked "nice" but didn't work properly. I am trying to fix the issues, but now I am kinda stuck.
When I select the designated "Checkout" page as the checkout page in the WooCommerce advanced settings, it appears as its should, only it has the console font and lots of spaces between all the text lines.
Same happens if I set the designated "Cart" page as the cart page in Woocommerce settings (Advanced tab), the page appear just like the checkout page, same console font and lots of spaces between all the text lines.
The pages works good without having them set as the official pages, but the cart-icon button won't link to any page if not set.
I have found a way to fix the font style problem and the stretching. The remainging problem now is that the checkout page layout are appearing on both pages, which means there is no "cart" page where the customers can edit qty and remove objects from the cart.
Anyone have a solution for this problem or have had it yourself?
All the pages are made with the Divi content builder.

Case Resolved! I fixed the problem. I added the "Woo Cart-products" and "Woo Checkout" blocks instead of manually using text fields with the [woocommerce_cart] key.
